# Can an Android Service detect if an event was consumed by App or not?

Tags: android, events, android-service, keyevent, android-event

I am running an Android application. An event happened (i.e. user double pressed the home key). There can be two possibilities,

1. The application consumed the event and passed (or restrict passing) to the lower layer
2. The application did not consumed the event and passed to the lower layer

From a service running in background (possibly a system service) is it possible to detect if the event was consumed by the application layer or not (in other words, if the option 1 happened or not)?